# How can we take derivatives on $UV$ w.r.t a vector $\mathbf{x}$ by using the chain rule and $d(UV)=dU\cdot V + U\cdot dV$?

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule, hessian-matrix

There is an example about this question on Page 564 in Chapter 11 of [B&V's Convex Optimization book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/). It presents the gradient and Hessian matrix of the following log barrier function,

> $$\tag{11.5}
> \phi(x)=-\sum_{i=1}^m \log(-f_i(x))
> $$
> $$
> \nabla \phi(x)=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{-f_i(x)} \nabla f_i(x)\\
> \nabla^2 \phi(x)=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{f_i(x)^2} \nabla f_i(x)\nabla f_i(x)^T+\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{-f_i(x)} \nabla^2 f_i(x)
> $$

I could not figure out the first term of the Hessian. According to the chain rule and the product rule, $U=\frac{1}{-f_i(x)}$ and $V=\nabla f_i(x)$, and $dU=\frac{1}{f_i(x)^2}\nabla f_i(x)$. Hence, the first term of the Hessian is supposed to be $dU\cdot V=\frac{1}{f_i(x)^2}\nabla f_i(x)\cdot \nabla f_i(x)$, but it does not satisfy the requirement of matrix product for dimensionality since $\nabla f_i(x)$ is a vector. I know the quoted form for the first term of Hessian meets the dimensionality requirement and makes sense in the respective of dimensionality consistency with the second term. Can anybody give me some instruction on this kind of case for calculating derivatives using both chain rule and pruduct rule simultaneously? I will appreciate any instructions.

Comment: I think this is one of those instances where the confusion stems from a poor choice of notation, not in the least because $\nabla^2$ typically denotes the Laplacian. For the Hessian, the first $\nabla$ and the second are not the same. One way to see this is to expand $\nabla$ in vector form as $\nabla = \sum_{j}\mathbf{e}_j\partial_j$, where $\mathbf{e}_i$ denotes some standard basis vector. Then the Hessian would be $\nabla\nabla^{\mathrm{T}} = \sum_{i,j}\mathbf{e}_i\mathbf{e}_j^\mathrm{T}\partial_i\partial_j$. That should make it clear where your missing transpose is.

Comment: @EuYu Your comment is helpful to understand Hessian. However, the first term is only to calculate first derivative twice independently which is not based on a computed first derivative. The second term is $\nabla^2$ which is supposed to be expanded as $\nabla\nabla^T$ as you have explained. Is my understanding correct? Hopefully, you can explain more about the first term.

Comment: I'm not sure I've fully understood your question. The prescription to calculate the Hessian is essentially to take the transpose of the gradient and then apply a second gradient. You can then apply the product/chain rules in their usual forms. Doing so gives the two terms as written, where $\nabla^2$ is interpreted as $\nabla\nabla^T$ in my notation. The first term is just the other term of the product rule. I'm not sure where your confusion is, but if it helps, I want to emphasize that there is nothing new conceptually here beyond ordinary calculus, just new (and poor) notation.

Comment: Your comments are very helpful, esp. "The prescription to calculate the Hessian is essentially to take the transpose of the gradient and then apply a second gradient.". My question is on the first term. Can we think of the first term as taking the transpose of the gradient as a whole and then apply a second gradient on the U part(the coefficient of the gradient) using product/chain rules?

Comment: That's exactly what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the nature of the cost function,
we can reason on a single component
and sum everything at the end.
The differential readily writes
$$
d\phi
= 
\frac{-df_n}{f_n}
$$

Introducing the gradient column vector
$\nabla f_n(\mathbf{x})$ , we can write
$
df_n
=
(\nabla f_n)^T d\mathbf{x}
$.

The gradient is thus
$$
\mathbf{g}
=
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
=
\frac{-1}{f_n} \nabla f_n (\mathbf{x})
$$

Introducing the Hessian matrix
$d\nabla f_n = 
\mathbf{H}_{f_n} d\mathbf{x}$,
it follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
d\mathbf{g}
&=&
\frac{df_n}{f_n^2} \nabla f_n (\mathbf{x}) 
-\frac{1}{f_n} (d\nabla f_n) \\
&=&
\frac{1}{f_n^2} \nabla f_n (\mathbf{x})
(\nabla f_n)^T d\mathbf{x}  
-\frac{1}{f_n} \mathbf{H}_{f_n} d\mathbf{x}
\end{eqnarray*}
The Hessian is thus
$$
\mathbf{H}_\phi=
\frac{1}{f_n^2} \nabla f_n (\mathbf{x})
(\nabla f_n)^T 
-\frac{1}{f_n} \mathbf{H}_{f_n}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a very informal answer, it can be formalised but it gets even more tedious and I think it is instructive to see where the terms come from using linear approximations.

The main issue is how we view derivatives, in particular the 2nd derivative.
Take a function $\psi:X \to Y$, then $\psi'(x) \in L(X,Y)$, that is a linear map from $X$ to $Y$. We write $\psi'(x)(h)$ to indicate $\psi'(x)$ applied to $h$.

In a similar manner, $\psi''(x) \in L(X,L(X,Y))$, that is a linear map from $X$ into the space of linear maps $L(X,Y)$. We could write $\psi''(x)(h)$ to indicate a map $L(X,Y)$ and $\psi''(x)(h)(w)$ to indicate that map evaluated at $w$. Since we can identify the space $L(X,L(X,Y))$ with the space of bilinear forms $X \times X \to Y$, it is more usual to write $\psi''(x)(h,w)$, and the matrix representation of $(h,w) \mapsto \psi''(x)(h,w)$ is the Hessian.

In particular, to first order, we have $\psi'(x+h)(w) \approx \psi'(x)(w)+ \psi''(x)(h,w)$.

Now consider a single term of the
form $\psi(x) = g(f(x))$. The chain rule gives $\psi'(x)(h) = g'(f(x))(f'(x)(h))$.

Now consider $\psi'(x+h^*)$ applied to $h$. To first order we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\psi'(x+h^*)(h) &=& g'(f(x+h^*))(f'(x+h^*)(h)) \\
&\approx& g'(f(x)+f'(x)(h^*))(f'(x+h^*)(h)) \\
&\approx& g'(f(x))(f'(x+h^*)(h))+g''(f(x))(f'(x)h^*,f'(x+h^*)(h)) \\
&\approx& g'(f(x))(f'(x)(h)+f''(x)(h^*,h))+g''(f(x))(f'(x)h^*,f'(x)(h)+f''(x)(h^*,h))\\
&=& g'(f(x))f'(x)(h) + g'(f(x))(f''(x)(h^*,h)) + g''(f(x))(f'(x)h^*,f'(x)(h)) + g''(f(x))(f'(x)h^*,f''(x)(h^*,h))
\end{eqnarray}
If we retain the first order terms in $h^*$ we get
$\psi''(x)(h^*,h) = g'(f(x))(f''(x)(h^*,h)) + g''(f(x))(f'(x)h^*,f'(x)(h))$.

Now let $g(t) = - \log (-t)$, since this is scalar valued we write $g'(t) = - {1 \over t}$, $g''(t) = {1 \over t^2}$.

If we use the notation $f'(x)(h) = \nabla f(x)^T h$ and $f''(x)(h^*,h) = (h^*)^T \nabla^2 f(x) h$ we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\psi''(x)(h^*,h) &=& - {1 \over f(x)} (h^*)^T \nabla^2 f(x) h + {1 \over f(x)^2} \nabla f(x)^T h^* \nabla f(x)^T h \\
&=& (h^*)^T \left[ - {1 \over f(x)} \nabla^2 f(x) + {1 \over f(x)^2} \nabla f(x) \nabla f(x)^T \right] h 
\end{eqnarray}
and so
$\nabla^2 \psi(x) = - {1 \over f(x)} \nabla^2 f(x) + {1 \over f(x)^2} \nabla f(x) \nabla f(x)^T$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time. I believe that you have a very deep understanding about this topic. Honestly, I haven't understood your answer. My issue is on the notations you use, e.g. your definitions of three linear maps, esp. $\psi^{'}$ and $\psi^{''}$. More specifically, you used several pairs of brackets in one notation, what did you mean by "applied to h"? What's the difference between $h^{\ast}$ and $h$?

Comment: @suineg Unfortunately the issue is one of notation and it is messy. The $\psi$ is meant to be a (twice differentiable) function. Then $\psi'(x)$ is the derivative of $\psi$ at the point $x$. This is a linear map. In the $\psi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ case, we  often just write this as $\psi(x+h) -\psi(x) \approx \psi'(x)h$ where $\psi'(x)$ is interpreted as a row vector applied to the vector ('perturbation') $h$. In the above, I want to make it clear (or at least try to :-)) that I am applying the linear map $\psi'(x)$ to the vector $h$, and so I write $\psi'(x)(h)$.

Comment: @suineg The second derivative can be viewed in two ways. As the derivative of $\psi'$ evaluated at $x$ we have $\psi''(x)$ which is again a linear map. However, this is a linear map from the '$h$' space to into the space of linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. That is, $\psi''(x)(h)$ is itself a map from  $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. So, to return to the space that $\psi(x)$ lives in, we need to apply this linear map to a vector to get something like $\psi''(x)(h)(h')$, where $h'$ is another vector.

Comment: The map $(h,h') \mapsto \psi''(x)(h)(h')$ is a bilinear map, and so instead of viewing it a a linear map to linear maps, we just write it as a bilinear map (Think of a map $(x,y) \mapsto x^T H y$, where $H$ is a square matrix). So, instead of the above notation, we write $\psi''(x)(h,h')$.

Comment: The $h,h^*$ are just two different vectors. Usually when we deal with the Hessian, we have $h=h^*$.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is messy no matter how you slice it up :-(.

Comment: All your comments are helpful. Thanks for your time. I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\sd{\cdot}\def\dd{:}
\def\o{{\large\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\H{{\cal H}}
\def\B{\Big}\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\B(#1\B)}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad&\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$For typing convenience, define the Jacobian and Hessian of $f(x)$ as
$$\eqalign{
J &= \grad{f}{x}
  &\qiq J_{ij} = \grad{f_i}{x_j}
  &\qiq df = J\sd dx \\
\H &= \grad{J}{x}
  &\qiq \H_{ijk} = \grad{J_{ij}}{x_k}
  &\qiq dJ = \H\sd dx \\
}$$
and the following vector variables
$$\eqalign{
a &= \o \oslash f \qiq A = \Diag{a},\;\; a=A\sd\o \\
da &= -a\odot a\odot df \;&\;=\quad -A^2\sd J\sd dx \\
b &= \log(-f) \\
db &= a\odot df &\;=\qquad A\sd J\sd dx \\
}$$
where `log()` is applied elementwise,
$\;\{\odot,\oslash\}$ denote elementwise multiplication and division, and $\;\{\sd\}$ denotes the dot-product. The *all-ones* vector is $\o$.

Now write the barrier function and calculate its gradient using the above notation.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= -\o\sd b \\
d\phi &= -\o\sd db \\
 &= -\o\sd \LR{A\sd J\sd dx} \\
 &= -\LR{J^T\sd A\sd \o}\sd dx \\
 &= -\LR{J^T\sd a}\sd dx \\
\grad{\phi}{x} &= -\;{J^T\sd a} \;\;\doteq\;\; g \\
}$$
So that's the gradient, now calculate the gradient of the gradient (i.e. the Hessian).
$$\eqalign{
dg &= -\;{J^T\sd da} \;-\; dJ^T\sd a \\
 &= \LR{J^T\sd A^2\sd J\sd dx} \;-\; \LR{\H\sd dx}^T\sd a \\
 &= \BR{J^T\sd A^2\sd J \;-\; a\sd\H}\sd dx \\
\grad{g}{x}
 &= {J^T\sd A^2\sd J \;-\; a\sd\H}
 \;\;\doteq\;\; \grad{^2\phi}{x\,\partial x^T} \\
}$$
Writing this in index notation might make things clearer
$$\eqalign{
\grad{^2\phi}{x_i\,\partial x_j}
 &= \LR{\sum_{k=\o}^m\sum_{\ell=\o}^m J_{ki}\,A^2_{k\ell}\,J_{\ell j}}
 \;-\; \LR{\sum_{k=\o}^m a_k\;\H_{kij}} \\
}$$